# Is there a way to keep a folder in its directory but still have it sync with Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, shared-folders

I have a folder I'd like to make available via Dropbox, but I don't want to place it in the Dropbox folder.

I'd like it to stay in the same directory that it's in. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use symlinks.

On Linux:

```
ln -s
```

Everywhere else:

Check out the
[Dropbox wiki](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/sync-other-folders)

Comment: Remember, symlinks once get visited once per Dropbox application starting to prevent symlink infinite loops. This means any subsequent changes per session do not get synced, but only after you restart Dropbox. Or you can use Bittorrent Sync which syncs by folders and doesn't require folders to be underneath a specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend uploading it through the Dropbox website itself. You can upload your files there in a folder, and they will be on your dropbox while still being in the directory.